# WPF converter implied in custom control?

Tags: wpf, binding, custom-controls, dependency-properties

In my WPF Custom Control which draws a pie chart, I successfully made it draw a pie chart given a set of values in a string, for example "10 20 30" would draw a pie chart with correct proportions. I bound the DrawingImage's drawing property to a converter to convert from the string into a DrawingGroup. This worked great, but I am trying to bypass the need for a converter.

Here is my MainWindow:

```
<Grid Margin="10">

    <local:PieChart DrawingCode="289 666 1337 780" Width="400" Height="400" RingWidth="300" Background="White" />

</Grid>
```

Here is my template for the custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PieChart}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PieChart}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage Drawing="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DrawingCode}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                    <Ellipse Width="{TemplateBinding RingWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding RingWidth}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And finally, here is my attempt at the Custom Control class:

```
public class PieChart : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawingCodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DrawingCode", typeof(string), typeof(PieChart), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RingWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RingWidth", typeof(double), typeof(PieChart), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    static PieChart()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PieChart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PieChart)));
    }

    public string DrawingCode
    {                                    
        get { return DrawingCodeConverter((string)GetValue(DrawingCodeProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(DrawingCodeProperty, value); }
    }

    public double RingWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RingWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RingWidthProperty, this.Width - value); }
    }

    public DrawingGroup DrawingCodeConverter(string value)
    {
        // This converter works but is long so I removed it from the post.
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the data types I should be using.  Also, if there is a completely different way to do this that I am ignorant of, please let me know. Also note that RingWidth is not the problem, it is DrawingCode.

Answer (score 1):

The getter and setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property may be bypassed when the property is accessed in XAML or by a Binding, Style Setter, Animation, etc. WPF then calls GetValue and SetValue directly. The reason is explained in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties)

You must therefore not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the getter and setter. Instead, declare your dependency property with a `PropertyChangedCallback` like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawingCodeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DrawingCode",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(PieChart),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DrawingCodePropertyChanged));

public string DrawingCode
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DrawingCodeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DrawingCodeProperty, value); }
}

private static void DrawingCodePropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var pieChart = (PieChart)o;
    pieChart.SetDrawingCode((string)e.NewValue);
}

private void SetDrawingCode(string drawingCode)
{
    var drawingGroup = DrawingCodeConverter(drawingCode);
    // do something with drawingGroup 
}
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused on exactly how I should be binding to this and where I put the logic in the PieChart control to convert from string to drawinggroup. Thanks!

Comment: You would put the code to convert the string to drawinggroup in the     private void SetDrawingCode()
    {
        //Put Instance DrawingCode Property Changed code here
        DrawingCodeConverter(DrawingCode);
    }

Comment: In your example, you put DrawingCodeConverter(DrawingCode) but my method returns a DrawingGroup from a string. So if I get the DrawingGroup in the SetDrawingCode() method, what do I do with it after that? Sorry for all the questions I'm just struggling to wrap my head around this

Comment: private void SetDrawingCode()
        {
            DrawingGroup dg = DrawingCodeConverter(DrawingCode);
        }

Comment: Basically, what do I do to bind to this variable dg?

Comment: @Clemens I've read the post but I don't know why you linked it to me? I've only asked for clarification in the comments and I have upvoted the answer because it had useful information but haven't marked it as a solution because it hasn't completely answered my question. All I want to know is what to do in the comment //do something with drawingGroup. I just don't know how to bind to that and I haven't gotten an answer yet

Comment: I've linked that article from the Help Center, because you havent't yet *accepted* any of the answers to your questions. You may also do that with your own answers. It indicates that the problem is solved.